# Check if an element get an attribute

Tags: jquery

How with jQuery I can check if an element get an attribute ?

Example:

```
<img class="photo_image">
```

Do not have the `src` attribute.

I'm using:

```
if($(v).find('img.photo_image').length) { }
```

But it not check it the `<img>` has a src attribute or not.
Thanks.

Comment: `if($(v).find('img[src].photo_image').length) { }`

Comment: or you can use `.attr()`.

Answer (score 0):

The [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function will return `undefined` if the attribute isn't set.

```
if ((typeof $('img.photo_image').attr('src')) == 'undefined') { // src is not set
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is this one:

```
var attr = $('.photo_image').attr('src');

// For some browsers, `attr` is undefined; for others,
// `attr` is false.  Check for both.
if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see if an element has an attribute, use the following code:

```
if ($("img[src]").length > 0)
```

If you want elements without an attribute, try:

```
if ($("img:not([src])").length > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img id="photo_image" />


var image = $('body').find('img#photo_image');

if (image.length) {
 if (image.attr('src')) {
  console.log('src is set');     
 }
 else {
  console.log('src is not set'); 
 }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1qyag2je/